# What is this red light in lower right hand corner?

Tags: notification

Here is a screen shot. Its not there after I restart but appears again:

[image: red light]

Comment: It's the in-built screencaster for gnome-shell. Ctrl-Alt-Shift-R to activate it.

Comment: thank you how does it start on its own and where does recording go?

Answer (score 11):

That is Gnome Shell's Screencast Recording feature. This lets you record videos of your desktop.

The screencaster is activated and deactivated with <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. Videos are automatically stored to the videos folder in the `WebM` format with the name `Screencast from %d%u-%c`.

[Source: The Gnome Shell features page.](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/Features)